# Are questions about PTC arbortext welcome?

Tags: discussion

I read the topics page, it does say TEX, LaTEX, etc... or "and related systems", yet I am not sure if this is where I could try for PTC arbortext answers.

---

Arbortext and styler are pretty common, but the consensus about it is that it lacks the most basic support. There is a forum where you can ask, and you will either get no answers, or a user-provided answer.

Well, since the answers are provided by the community, I don't think it's fair that they reside on the developer's forum. So I would love to see it on the SE network.

---

So, is this where I should start asking questions?

Comment: Starter: does Arbortext use TeX? My understanding has been that it may have once used TeX or at least some of the routines, but is today not at all related.

Comment: I don't think it does. I just thought it fit under "Related software and tools, BibTeX, MakeIndex, Lyx, etc.", but indeed I am not sure. Also, arbortext was mentionned in a few questions as an alternative to *Tex.

Comment: 'Related' is usually taken to cover TeX derivatives such as pdfTeX, XeTex, LuaTeX and tools which form part of the same chain, such as BibTeX, MakeIndex, Biber. Alternatives to TeX are normally only on-topic in questions covering that area directly.

Comment: I was right to ask then. Do you know of a more general XML based styling / authoring software community? It seems to me there could be enough of a community to support it...